# How to ping to the vpn server, from outside the vpn, when connected?

Tags: vpn, ping

If I'm connected to a vpn, and I ping the vpn server, the ping will go via the vpn, so I'm not really testing my local ping with the server.
How can I test my local ping to the server, when connected to the vpn?

Comment: Pinging the public IP address of the VPN server will never go through the VPN.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with _vpn server_ in this case? If you mean the remote endpoint of the VPN connection then _using its public IP address_ should never go through the VPN tunnel as @Appleoddity said since otherwise the connection would abort quiet fast. Maybe add to your question how you determined that your ping is going through the VPN.